# Nested printf statements working

Tags: c, printf

I can't understand how are the following codes giving different outputs

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int i=43;
        printf("%d\n",printf("%d",printf("%d",i)));
        return 0;
}
```

output: `4321`

```
printf("%d\n",printf("%d",printf("%d ",i)));
```

output: `43 31`

```
printf("%d\n",printf("%d ",printf("%d ",i)));
```

output: `43 3 2`

```
printf("%d\n",printf("%d ",printf(" %d ",i)));
```

output `43 4 2`

```
printf("%d\n",printf(" %d ",printf(" %d ",i)));
```

output: `43 4 3`

and other variations give other outputs too.

How can just a space change a number.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This `printf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) might help you. Take a look at what the function returns.

Comment: Why would you ever do this?

Comment: I am not doing this in my program. I came across a puzzle and I was confused how can mere spaces change a number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`printf` return the number of characters printed

In your case that statement can be broken like this - the output is expected:

```
    printf("%d\n", // 1
           printf("%d", // 2
                  printf("%d",i)    // 43
                 )
          );  // 4321
```

For more information, consult the standard `fprintf` (`printf` is special case of `fprintf` with the stream being `stdout`)

> 7.21.6.1 The fprintf function

```
 #include <stdio.h>
       int fprintf(FILE * restrict stream,
           const char * restrict format, ...);
```

> The fprintf function **returns the number of characters transmitted**, or a negative value if an output or encoding error occurred.

Comment: It'd be nice if you quoted and linked some documentation

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson agreed, I added the `fprintf` reference